# Should objects be declared const or let?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Whether an object is declared `const` or `let` in ES2015 doesn't affect assignment to its properties:

```
> let a = {}
undefined
> const b = {}
undefined
> a.y = 3
3
> b.y = 3
3
> a
{ y: 3 }
> b
{ y: 3 }
```

Is there a good reason to prefer one form of declaration over the other?